# Html form doesn't send double variable to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have html form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowAddedProduct", "AddProductsDialog",FormMethod.Post,
        new {id="AddProdForm" }))
    {          
        <p>Price:</p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { type="number",Class = "EnterProductInfoField"});
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Price);
        <input id="submitValidation" type="submit" value="Add" />
    }
```

If i enter integer value in textbox like `700`.It sends valid `Price` field for model to ShowAddedProduct Action method ,but when i enter decimal number like `422.65`,it doesn't sends it and i get in action method `Price`=0.Type of `Price` is `double`

Here is ShowAddedProduct method code.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowAddedProduct(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage)
        {

            product.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            if (uploadedImage != null && uploadedImage.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(uploadedImage.InputStream))
                {
                    product.Picture = reader.ReadBytes(uploadedImage.ContentLength);
                }
            }
            using (GoodsContainer1 container = new GoodsContainer1())
            {

                product.SubCategory = container.SubCategorySet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == product.SubCategory_Id);
                if (product.Article != null
                    && product.Name != null
                    && product.Picture != null
                    && product.Price != 0)
                {
                    container.ProductSet.Add(product);
                    container.SaveChanges();                   
                    return PartialView("~/Views/AddProductsDialog/AddedProduct.cshtml",product);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("AddProducts");
        }
```

Here is model code for html form.

```
  public partial class Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Product()
        {
            this.DescriptionParameters = new HashSet<DescriptionParameters>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Article { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public int SubCategory_Id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<DescriptionParameters> DescriptionParameters { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have an action with double input? share you controllers code for that action

Comment: Just added controller code and model code.

Comment: What is the culture on the server. Is it one that accepts a `.` (dot) as a decimal separator?

Comment: I changed Regional and Laguage culture settings,from `,` to `.` and it works.But i still don't understant,why it didn't work,even when i used  `,`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of mvc internal annotation. change

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { type="number",Class = "EnterProductInfoField"})
```

to

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Price, new { type="number",Class = "EnterProductInfoField"})
```

Comment: Thanks for hint,finally it works validation,for "." and "," in number.But it didn't solve problem for me.

Comment: delete "type="number" .

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { Class = "EnterProductInfoField"})
```

Delete type="number", because it sets your value as integer (not double)